# how to get a source url in jw player withe javascript command

Tags: javascript, url, video, get, jwplayer

im new in javascript and i try to get a video url from a site using java script 
without looking for it in the page source 
the page source is like this

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("myJwVideo").setup({
    playlist: [{
        image: "http://www.blabla.com/back.jpg",
        sources: [{ 
            file: "http:www.videourl.mp4"   
        }]
    }],
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

is there is a way to get the **http:www.videourl.mp4** url using javascript in firefox or google chrome console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jwplayer("myJwVideo").getPlaylist().

Documentation at http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#all

Comment: than x a lot man that was very help-full i even find another way


             jwplayer("myJwVideo").getPlaylistItem()['file'];